# AccessDeniedException when Creating a recently deleted file

Tags: java, io

I am trying to delete a file and then recreate it. First I check to see if the file already exists, then, if it does, I delete it. Then I try to create a new file in the same place with the same name. When I do this I get this error:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: inputLog.txt
```

However, if the file did not exist before running these three operations, then the file is created without issue.

Here is my code:

```
final Path INPUTLOGPATH = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("inputLog.txt");
try {
    reader = Files.newBufferedReader(INPUTLOGPATH, charset);
} catch (IOException e) {
    reader = null;
}

if (reader != null) {
    try {
        Files.delete(INPUTLOGPATH);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

try {
    Files.createFile(INPUTLOGPATH);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First I check to see if the file already exists, then, if it does, I delete it.

Why? Opening the file for output will already do all that. You're just repeating work that the operating system already has to do. Remove all this. You're doing it wrong by not closing the file reader, but it's irrelevant. Don't write unnecessary code.

> Then I try to create a new file in the same place with the same name

That is also unnecessary as shown. Just open the file for output when you need it.

As you have it now:

- you're opening the file, which is a search, among many other things
- you're deleting the file, which is another search
- you're creating the file, which is another search
- then presumably you're opening the file for output, which requires another search, another deletion, and another creation, internally to the operating system.

Don't do this. Just remove all this code. It accomplishes exactly nothing.

You're also introducing all kinds of timing-window problems by this approach, and you still have to deal with eventual failure at the point where you actually open the file for output.

Comment: After reader is initialized the file is read from all the way through once, and after the file is deleted and then recreated it is never used again in the entire life cycle of the program, until the program itself is restarted. If you look at the code, when I check to see if the file already exists, all I do is refer back to work that was done earlier, I'm not doing any work besides checking a boolean. I do need to recreate the file, because I need the file to be empty.

Comment: Please just assume that there is other code in between the given code that is not the cause of the problem I am having but that makes the code I have necessary and answer the question.

Comment: I have answered the question. You aren't closing the file reader, and removing most or all of this code will fix the immediate problem, and several others you haven't foreseen. `new FileWriter()` is sufficient. Or nothing, if you never read the file again. I can only comment on code that you've actually posted, and I'm certainly not prepared to assume the rest of it is bug free given what you have posted here.